# "src property" not getting a value from External JavaScript file or another script block

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get "src" value of the image tag and displaying in an alert box.
Alert box message says: "undefined." It works if the script is contained in one block. But fetching a value from outside a script block from another or from an external JavaScript file, loses the saved value.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test src</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var y = document.getElementById('content');
var z = y.src;
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="content" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/17/19/04/adorable-2861801_960_720.png">
  <script>
       alert(z); // undefined?
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when this line `var y = document.getElementById('content');` executed, the element img is not ready, therefore y is null and y.src is undefined, if you change to `var z = "test"`, then you could see that alert show correct :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test src</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var y = document.getElementById('content');
var z = "test";
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="content" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/17/19/04/adorable-2861801_960_720.png">
  <script>
       alert(z); // undefined?
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how to fix it ? you could put the line `var y = document.getElementById('content');`  in the script block after the img element is declared:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test src</title>

</head>
<body>

  <img id="content" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/10/17/19/04/adorable-2861801_960_720.png">
  <script>
       var y = document.getElementById('content');
       var z = y.src;
      
      
   </script>
</body>
 <script>
       var y = document.getElementById('content');
       var z = y.src;
       alert(z); // undefined?
      
   </script>
</html>
```